# how to resolve typescript issue with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I have an issue with this code

```
    const doc = await req.db
      .collection('clients')
      .find({}, { lName: 1, fName: 1, id: 1 })
```

giving the typescript error

```
Type error: Argument of type '{ lName: number; fName: number; id: number;  }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOptions<any>'.
```

how can I fix this?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

This should resolve it for you:

```
const doc = await req.db
    .collection<Client>('clients')
    .find({ lName: "", fName: "", id: 1 })
```

### Explaination

The `.find()` method of `Db` takes one or two options, where the first option is the `FilterQuery` and the second is `FindOneOptions`.

```
find<T = TSchema>(query?: FilterQuery<TSchema>): Cursor<T>;
find<T = TSchema>(query: FilterQuery<TSchema>, options?: FindOneOptions<T extends TSchema ? TSchema : T>): Cursor<T>;
```

The [options](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find) for the second argument are things like `sort` and `limit`, not the object to find.  What you have in the second argument is the `FilterQuery` which needs to be the first argument.

The `FilterQuery` type is generic, so in order for typescript to know that we are filtering clients, we need to pass the generic  when calling `collection<Client>('clients')`.  That will cause it to return a collection of `Client`.

This is the interface I used, but I'm sure there are more properties

```
interface Client {
    lName: string;
    fName: string; 
    id: number;
}
```

Now, if you pass an invalid type to `.find()`, typescript knows and will throw and error.

```
.find({ lName: 1, fName: 1, id: 1 })
```

This is now an error because I said that `fName` and `lName` must be `string`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCICMC%20cBmUIjgIhAgDsBzCAExXwG4BYAKEeGJgFMpMBDAYzbgDCAG2BtWiRnClwhAOS4g2ALjgBnGFBal6DaVnmKV6zWRpxJ04BRXEAriBQcdaRox4l1cCAGsAYreIeOABeOC5VAE9AgAo4KhVUAEoQgD4JXWkoNhhbKGIwgHcuYHgqCz0AOnchITYeGGASAB5hUVYU6IByHhExGFVOxPLpCswWCmiEGQNlAnwAGn0FWfwFuCsVAEY4NCGGFyYGd2JPFC4Kf0CQsMir2Pi4JNT0vSycvMLi0pRhqSqIGp1BrNVp9DrdXqsAZ7PR-MbECZTOTLLaLTAzVHraxwba7RhoIA)

Comment: In your find you aren't returning all fields. `.find({ lName: 1, fName: 1, id: 1 })` needs to be `.find({}, { lName: 1, fName: 1, id: 1 })` to have ALL ENTRIES returned while only selecting certain fields from EVERY entry.